# Best word that describes self choices to do hard work and be committed to

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best word, term or etc that indicates loyalty along with the obligation to do something
Conditions:

1. Positive meaning
2. Show the situation that a person has chosen this things with Personal choice and satisfaction to got tasks done
3. The shorter and more specific it is, the better
4. I want to use this word in an essay in a news paper and want to it be easy to massive number of crowd
5. It should be easy to pronounce

Comment: Please give a context where you would use the term.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Whether you are looking for one word (See [*About single word requests*](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)), a phrase, or an idiom, you should provide (a) a detailed description to the best of your ability, (b) what terms you have tried that don't work, and (c) a **sample sentence** where you would use the term. Currently, the description you have provided could be clearer, and your question lacks words you've tried and a sample sentence.

Comment: We need a sentence!

Comment: Give a sentence like "X impresses Y with the quality of _______". Without a sentence people can only guess.

Comment: If you use words you  don't know in your résumé it can be considered disqualifying.

Comment: I want to use this word instead of achievement for great success in life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a virtue could be described as

***abnegation*** (also self-abnegation)

> renunciation of your own interests in favor of the interests of others

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abnegation) says:

> When you purposely deny yourself something, especially in favor of the needs of others, you would describe this act as an abnegation. ***This has to be your choice***, not the choice of others — so it's not abnegation when your parents don't let you stay out all night.

Look at this example provided by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abnegation)

> Her wartime letters, showing her ***abnegation***, selfless duty and distress, make impressive reading. (The Times Literary Supplement - 2012)

A person who has abnegation will derive satisfaction from and delight in the very act of sacrificing themselves for the others.

Comment: The question is unclear in far too many ways for anybody to be sure that this (or anything else) is what the OP had in mind. To begin with, it is not at all clear what the role of the word *self* in the question is.

Comment: Commitment, obligation and loyalty are also considerable

Comment: @F4r5h4d: if you want your question to remain open, you must include in its body a sentence where you would use this term. If you have so many options, then why did you ask the question?

Comment: I know what you mean  but i want to use it as a single word for a application

Answer (score -1):

You may find this if you look up a list of synonyms of 'loyal/ty', but such lists do not inform about different nuances and differing distributions.

> **fealty** ...
>
> 2: intense fidelity
>
> - *the fealty of country music fans to their favorite stars* [Nicholas Dawidoff]

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fealty)]

The original sense informs the now more usually found one:

> 1a: the fidelity of a vassal or feudal tenant to his lord
>
> b: the obligation of such fidelity

So both the sense of obligation / veneration (from M-W senses 1a/b), and the intense loyalty (sense 2), are covered.

Comment: This would have been an OK answer if the question had been simply 'What is a synonym for loyalty?' But is that what the question was? And does *fealty* satisfy the OP's fourth condition?

Comment: The 'obligation' aspect is, as stated, also addressed. // OP doesn't seem fazed by _abnegation_ [[Google 1-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fealty%2Cabnegation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfealty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabnegation%3B%2Cc0)] I rarely do other than CV on questions with umpteen requirements like this, but 'fealty' does seem to come close to addressing both semantic requirements.